# Locate the path of STL headers used by g++

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, g++, msys

I need to look something up in the debug version of `std::vector<T>`, and I can't remember where the headers actually are. This is under MSYS on Windows, where this is tricky, because you have `/include`, `/mingw/include`, `/mingw/mingw32/include`, `/usr/include`, and I still can't find them...

I know one way, that is to write a file like this:

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Then

```
$ g++ -E temp.cpp | grep vector
```

And we find that it's here: `/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++/vector`

But is there a faster way? Can we ask `g++` without using this trick?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can display the full search paths with

```
g++ -print-search-dirs
```

or you can find a specific header without writing a source file with something along the lines of

```
echo '#include <vector>' | g++ -x c++ -E - | grep '/vector"'
```

Comment: That's great! For Windows users like me, the slash in the grep pattern should be dropped.